# Updating global DataTable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, global-variables

In the program I am trying to set a datatable as a global variable, and then in a different class edit the row that has the selected ID in a list box. It works to an extent that if I select an ID it will set the variable and when I try to use it in a different class to edit the details in the database, it does not display the selected ID's row, it displays the last row in the database instead.

Code for setting the global variable:

```
  FileReader details = new FileReader();
        Guest gst = new Guest();
        DataTable guestDetails;
        guestDetails = details.LoadingGuestsFromDatabase();

        foreach (DataRow row in guestDetails.Rows)
        {
            if (lstGuest.SelectedItem.ToString() == row["Guest_ID"].ToString())
           {

            lblName.Text = row["Name"].ToString();
            lblEmail.Text = row["Email"].ToString();
            lblAge.Text = row["Age"].ToString();
            lblPhoneNo.Text = row["Phone_Number"].ToString();
            lblRoomType.Text = row["Room_Type"].ToString();


                 Globals.setCurrent(guestDetails);
        }
```

When setCurrent is set with the guestDetails DataTable, it then moves on to the form for editing guests which is as follows:

```
   DataTable editedGuest;
        editedGuest = Globals.getCurrent();


        foreach (DataRow rows in editedGuest.Rows)
        {

            txtUpdateName.Text = rows["Name"].ToString();
            txtUpdateAge.Text = rows["Age"].ToString();
            txtUpdateEmail.Text = rows["Email"].ToString();
            txtUpdatePhone.Text = rows["Phone_Number"].ToString();

        }
```

Now what is meant to happen is that the details of the selected guest is to display and not the last one in the database! I'm not sure if I need  to create another SQL command to get the selected guest or not? Any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add some more code to it:

```
foreach (DataRow rows in editedGuest.Rows)
{
     if(rows["ID"].ToString().Equals(dropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString()))
     {
        txtUpdateName.Text = rows["Name"].ToString();
        txtUpdateAge.Text = rows["Age"].ToString();
        txtUpdateEmail.Text = rows["Email"].ToString();
        txtUpdatePhone.Text = rows["Phone_Number"].ToString();
        break;
      }
}
```

or you could use Linq to query the datatable.

Comment: Nah that aint working, due to that the list box isnt in the EditGuest Form its in the ViewGuest one where you select the ID to use.